# How to keep parent scope property and isolated scope property in sync?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following template:

```
<dynamic-field name="Name" type="input" ng-model="temp.product.name"></dynamic-field>
<dynamic-field name="Price" type="input" ng-model="temp.product.price"></dynamic-field>
<dynamic-field name="Qty" type="input" ng-model="temp.product.qty"></dynamic-field>
```

Custom directive code:

```
app.directive('dynamicField', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: getTemplate('templates/single-field.html'),
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
           // console.log($scope);
       }
   };
});
```

In directive template, the input field is displayed:

```
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" /> <!-- if $temp.product.post_text in parent scope is set to "Test", it's displayed -->
</div>
```

The problem is, when I modify something inside the input (isolated scope) changes are not applied to the parent scope. I think the problem is that I use primitive here:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" />
```

... but I'm not sure how to resolve this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be doing something wrong. If it's two-way bound, it's two-way bound.

```js
function MainController() {
  this.name = "test";
  this.logCtrlName = function() {
    alert(this.name);
  }
}

function dynamicField() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: `
      <div class="field">
        <input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" />
      </div>
    `,
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    }
  };
}

angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app')
  .controller('MainController', MainController)
  .directive('dynamicField', dynamicField);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
    <dynamic-field name="Name" type="input" ng-model="ctrl.name"></dynamic-field>
    <a href ng-click="ctrl.logCtrlName();">Name inside parent controller</a>: {{ ctrl.name | json }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like you said since your model is primitive value, so whenever you change the value inside isolated scope will create its copy of scope variable.

A simple and quick way to fix that is create a function to update parent scope value `$scope.$parent.ngModel` directly then add `ng-change` to input element and call that function whenever input value is changed.